# Inequality with radiuses in triangle.

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

Let $ABC$ a triangle and $O$ his circumcentre, H his orthocentre, I his  incentre.
If $R_1$ is  the radius of the circle circumscribed in triangle $OIH$ and $R$  the radius of the circle circumscribed in triangle $ABC$, prove that $R_1>{R\over2}$

Any ideas?

Comment: this inequality is emigrated from Aops

Comment: No, i found this problem 2 months ago in a romanian magazine.

Comment: yes i know this Problem and a partial solution can be found on Aops

Comment: can you send me a link from this Magazine?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/I8Sm6mU.jpg problem 27480

Comment: thank you very much and what is the Name of this Magazine?

Comment: The Magazine is "Gazeta matematica"

Comment: Idea: the distance of $I$ from the midpoint of $OH$ is exactly $\frac{R}{2}-r$, by Feuerbach's theorem. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628059/angle-between-triangle-orthocenter-center-of-inscribed-circle-and-centroid-is-a/2628680#2628680

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, may i know if you find any solution for this problem?